# Могут ли подпроекты cmake иметь ссылки друг на друга?

Tags: cmake

Добрый день! 
Проблема следующая, в смаке делю проект на подпроекты, так что в корневом смаке есть только add_directory(dir1) add_directory(dir2). При компиляции (по порядку - первой директории) - жалуется на `unresolved links` к классам второй директории, если поменять местами порядок компиляции - вторая папка будет жаловаться что не знает линков на первую.

Возник вопрос - а вообще так можно разделить проект и как избежать `unresolved links`? 
Работает вариант - когда в корневом смаке первая папка подключается не попдроектом, а просто файлы из нее перечисляются в `add_executable` а подпроектом идет только вторая папка. Но требуется чтоб в корневом были только add_directories

Comment: А подпроекты это собственно что? Статические библиотеки? Динамические?
Какой компилятор? Мне кажется cmake тут вообще не причем.
Да естественно cmake подпроекты могут зависеть от других проектов, но без циклических зависимостей конечно

Comment: нет, просто add_directory , не библиотеки

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не должно быть перекрёстных ссылок между проектами. Иначе как они могут быть собраны, если для сборки одного, нужно чтобы был собран другой и наоборот?
Выделяйте общий код в библиотеку, которую линкуйте в оба проекта, чтобы они зависели от библиотеки и не были зависимы друг от друга.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за ответ! Просто меня тут убеждали что нельзя делать перекрестные либы, а на с подпроектами проблем не должно быть (и иди кури маны).